# Pandas split list upon DataFrame creation

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file coming in, which I am doing some operations/trimming on.

The result looks like this:

```
print("User:", user)
> User: {'id': 1, 'label': 'female', 'position': {'lat': 47.72485566, 'lon': 10.32219439}, 'confidence': 0.8}
```

When applying `df = pd.DataFrame(user, index=[0])` I get the following Dataframe:

```
     id   label    position  velocity
0    1    female   NaN       0.8
```

When applying `df = pd.DataFrame(user)` I get:

```
      id   label    position     confidence
lat   1    female   47.72485566  0.8
lon   1    female   10.32219439  0.8
```

I am aware, as to why that happens, however none is what I want.

I'd like the following:

```
     id   label    lat          lon           confidence
0    1    female   47.72485566  10.32219439   0.8
```

However I am not sure what the best way is to split the position parameter.

Comment: Flatten the original dictionary `user` first, then apply `df = pd.DataFrame(user)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) , then later rename the columns:

```py
>>> df = pd.json_normalize({'id': 1, 'label': 'female', 'position': {'lat': 47.72485566, 'lon': 10.32219439}, 'confidence': 0.8})
>>> df = df.rename(columns={'position.lat': 'lattitude', 'position.lon': 'longitude'})
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
id   label  confidence  lattitude  longitude
0   1  female         0.8  47.724856  10.322194
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you want to remove the dict at 'position' and include it in the original dict

```py
user = {'id': 1, 'label': 'female', 'position': {'lat': 47.72485566, 'lon': 10.32219439}, 'confidence': 0.8}
user.update(user.pop('position'))  # happens in-place

pd.DataFrame(user, index=[0])


>>>    id   label   confidence  lat         lon
>>> 0   1   female  0.8         47.724856   10.322194
```

However, it seems the input data fits more to the idea of a pandas Series here:

```py
pd.Series(user)
```

EDIT: [The solution from ThePyGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72868537/15330539) seems more general on the cost of execution time. If this is critical or not depends on the situation.

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 10
user = {'id': 1, 'label': 'female', 'position': {'lat': 47.72485566, 'lon': 10.32219439}, 'confidence': 0.8}
df = pd.json_normalize(user)
df = df.rename(columns={'position.lat': 'lattitude', 'position.lon': 'longitude'})
>>> 811 µs ± 121 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 10
user = {'id': 1, 'label': 'female', 'position': {'lat': 47.72485566, 'lon': 10.32219439}, 'confidence': 0.8}
user.update(user.pop('position'))  # happens in-place
df = pandas.DataFrame(user, index=[0])
>>> 424 µs ± 45.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit -n 10 -r 10
user = {'id': 1, 'label': 'female', 'position': {'lat': 47.72485566, 'lon': 10.32219439}, 'confidence': 0.8}
user.update(user.pop('position'))  # happens in-place
df = pandas.Series(user)
>>> 167 µs ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I accepted ThePyGuy's answer as I agree it's more general especially for my simple question. However for what I have to do with the DataFrame created, your solution seems actually better.